# Yii2 url validation without http,https

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have used url validation code in my model,but it gives me error.
I just validate if user only put like google.com or yahoo.com not http,www required.
How i can do this.

```
 [['thankyou_page_url','confirmation_page_url'],'url'],
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not able to test it right now. But I think you need to add the `defaultScheme` option. The default value of `defaultScheme` is `null` which means there must be a valid scheme in the URL.

If you change it to

```
[['thankyou_page_url','confirmation_page_url'],'url', 'defaultScheme' => 'http'],
```

the http:// part will automatically be added if you don't supply anything in the input. I think if you set the `defaultScheme` to an empty string it will also allow URL's without a scheme. So maybe this works:

```
[['thankyou_page_url','confirmation_page_url'],'url', 'defaultScheme' => ''],
```

Comment: I set my default scheme to https, which works, except when the input has http:// already in it. Is it possible to make it overwrite if it's done with http?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, just remove shemes part from a pattern

```
['url', 'url', 'pattern'=>'/(([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)(\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+)(?::\d{1,5})?(?:$|[?\/#])/i'],
```